# Attach database to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

How do i load a database into SQL Server 2008 R2 express? SQL Server 2008, have a right click function on databases to add it. R2 don'r have the database folder. I checked the FAQ as best I could to find an answer but found nothing.

Thanks

Comment: Well, **my** R2 does have a database folder ... there must be something fundamentally wrong with your installation, I'm afraid. You should be able to attach your database just the same in R2 as in earlier versinos....

Comment: Thanks I will install it again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, if I understand the question, but I read it as you do not have a "Databases" folder under the connected database server. I am thinking if the problem is more on the connection..

I assume that you mean SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In my understand you can't create a database.Right click and add.Something missing in your installation.Try to full install it again.. or try to create using Query

```
Create Database <DB NAME>
```